# Codeigniter combine where_in and like active record queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, where-in

I have the following active record query:

```
$this->db->select('id, email, first_name, last_name, current_location_state, current_location, avatar, avatar_fb');
          $this->db->from('users');
          $this->db->like('first_name', $search);
          $this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
          $this->db->or_like("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)", $search);
          $this->db->or_like('email', $search);
          $this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
```

This is a function that has an array $ids, which has the ids of my friends. I want to search for friends that match my "like" queries, but only have one of the id's in the $ids variable.

I'm pretty sure i need to combine where_in and all the like statements so its something like (WHERE_IN $ids && Like Statements).

I'm not great at mysql so any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
function narrow_connections($search) {

       //First get all this users connections...
       $connections = $this->get_connections($this->session->userdata('user_id'), 0, 0);

       if(empty($connections)) {
          return array();
       }else {

          //Need to get an array of id's
          $ids = array();
          foreach($connections as $con) {
             array_push($ids, $con['id']);
          }

          //Now that we have an array of ID's, find all users that have one of the ids (our connections), AND match a search term to narrow down
          //the results. 

          $this->db->select('id, email, first_name, last_name, current_location_state, current_location, avatar, avatar_fb');
          $this->db->from('users');
          $this->db->like('first_name', $search);
          $this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
          $this->db->or_like("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)", $search);
          $this->db->or_like('email', $search);
          $this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
          $query = $this->db->get();
          $data = array();

          foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
          $data[] = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'email' => $row->email,
            'first_name' => $row->first_name,
            'last_name' => $row->last_name,
            'current_location_state' => $row->current_location_state,
            'current_location' => $row->current_location,
            'avatar' => $row->avatar,
            'avatar_fb' => $row->avatar_fb,
          );
          }
          return $data;

       }
     }
```

Comment: In codeigniter, it's easier to write such query using old, raw sql rather than `active record`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to find all the friends? If there are only one id, then you don't need `like` part, as you already found your friend. On the other part, if you not sure about `id` of your friends, and just want to find all friends matching your like criteria, you may remove `where_in` part.

This will find your friends:

```
$this->db->select('id, email, first_name, last_name, current_location_state, current_location, avatar, avatar_fb');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->like('first_name', $search);
$this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
$this->db->or_like("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)", $search);
$this->db->or_like('email', $search);
```

Considering there's only one id, such query will find only one friend:

```
$this->db->select('id, email, first_name, last_name, current_location_state, current_location, avatar, avatar_fb');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
```

**EDIT**

Sometimes, with codeigniter, it is better to use a raw query:

```
$this->db->query('
  SELECT `id`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `current_location_state`, `current_location`, `avatar`, `avatar_fb`
  FROM `users`
  WHERE (
    `first_name` like ?
    or `last_name` like ? 
    or concat(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) like ? 
    or `email` like ?)
  AND `id` in('
    .join(',',
    array_map(function($e) { return (int) $e; }, $ids))
    .')',
  "%$search%", "%$search%", "%$search%", "$search")->result();
```

Comment: Forgive me I should've specified that we're trying to narrow down our friends by name in this function. So we have a connections table with our "friends". So we get our friends ids in $ids. Then we're trying to say, of all the users with our friends ids, narrow down by the search term. I'll post more above.

Comment: @DanielWhite and what's the problem, then? Your code seems to be correct. What it's doing wrong?

Comment: its basically getting the ids of my connections just fine, but the "$this->db->like" statements are over riding the "where_in" and just returning all users that match the like statements. I want to return all users that match the like statements AND are one of my connections. So (where_in $ids AND (like statements)).

I just can't figure out how to write the SQL / Active record for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I had the same problem and got it solved by simply reorder the filters. This means: you first have to do the 'where' statetemnt (not 'where_in')

This would look like:

```
$this->db->select('id, email, first_name, last_name, current_location_state, current_location, avatar, avatar_fb');

      $this->db->where('id', $ids);
      $this->db->from('users');
      $this->db->like('first_name', $search);
      $this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
      $this->db->or_like("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)", $search);
      $this->db->or_like('email', $search);
```